# How can I attach Private End Point to Logic App created using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am creating a logic app using an ARM template and inside the ARM template, I am creating a Private Endpoint for the storage account, and this private endpoint I want to attach to the Logic App.

The private endpoint is getting created but not getting attached. I have searched but I didn't get any results or demo on the same.

Is there any way I can attach the existing private endpoint to my logic app using the ARM template, Via portal I am able to attach it but I want to use the ARM template to do so?

Below is the JSON template:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppFEname": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "use32BitWorkerProcess": {
      "type": "Bool"
    },
    "location": {
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location to deploy resources to."
      }
    },
    "subnetNameForPrivateEndpoint": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "hostingPlanFEName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "contentStorageAccountName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "skuCode": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "workerSizeId": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "numberOfWorkers": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "defaultValue": "VirtualNetwork",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the VNET that the Function App and Storage account will communicate over."
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "privateEndpointFileStorageName": "[concat(parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), '-fileshare-pe')]",
    "fileShareName": "[concat(toLower(parameters('logicAppFEname')), 'b86e')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('contentStorageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "defaultAction": "Deny"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
          "services": {
            "file": {
              "keyType": "Account",
              "enabled": true
            },
            "blob": {
              "keyType": "Account",
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), '/default/', toLower(variables('fileShareName')))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('contentStorageAccountName')]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('privateEndpointFileStorageName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares', parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), 'default',toLower(variables('fileShareName')))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subnet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetNameForPrivateEndpoint'))]"
        },
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "MyStorageQueuePrivateLinkConnection",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName'))]",
              "groupIds": [
                "file"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections": [],
        "subnet": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetNameForPrivateEndpoint') )]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "kind": "web",
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanFEName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {},
      "kind": "functionapp,workflowapp",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~3"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "node"
            },
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('logicAppFEname')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('logicAppFEname')), '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('contentStorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('contentStorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(variables('fileShareName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "APP_KIND",
              "value": "workflowApp"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__id",
              "value": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version",
              "value": "[1.*, 2.0.0)",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET",
              "value": "1",
              "slotSetting": false
            }
          ],
          "use32BitWorkerProcess": "[parameters('use32BitWorkerProcess')]",
          "cors": {
            "allowedOrigins": [
              "https://afd.hosting.portal.azure.net",
              "https://afd.hosting-ms.portal.azure.net",
              "https://hosting.portal.azure.net",
              "https://ms.hosting.portal.azure.net",
              "https://ema-ms.hosting.portal.azure.net",
              "https://ema.hosting.portal.azure.net",
              "https://ema.hosting.portal.azure.net"
            ]
          }
        },
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanFEName'))]",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": true
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "networkconfig",
          "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
          "name": "virtualNetwork",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
            "swiftSupported": true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanFEName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {},
      "sku": {
        "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
      },
      "kind": "",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanFEName')]",
        "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
        "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": "20"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ARM template shows few errors, I recommend using Visual Studio Code with ARM Template extension which will help you validate it.

Back to your problem, I suspect you attempt to achieve this
[[image: Azure Logic Apps with Storage Private Endpoint]

At the original Source an ARM template valid is present. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: But how can add a private endpoint using the ARM template to the logic app? We can add a private endpoint via the portal. But here in the ARM template, I am able to create it but it is not getting attached to the logic app. I want this created endpoint to get attached to the logic app.